# Apple In App Purchase - How to fetch a product's subscription duration from the app store?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

Can anyone tell me how to get an IAP subscription length?

I have an app.  I have defined a Auto Renewing Subscription product and I have defined 3 different subscription lengths for this product - 1 month, 6 months and 12 months.

I am able to poll the app store and fetch the IAP product information for my 3 subscriptions.

However - I can not fetch the subscription length.

Of course I know that product id #1 is 1 month.  But I can not get this length from Apple which means I'll have to hard code the duration into the app.

Surely there is a way to get a localised string that details the subscription length?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to store the durations in your app. Since you should already have a plist with your productIDs or at least an own server that stores the valid productIds you can also make a plist in your app bundle  that stores the productIDs as well as the durations. 
[image: PList with productIds]

And with durations: 
[image]